# Value of next in subscribe becomes undefined when using decorator on service function

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, decorator

I'm trying to transform all dates in a HTTP response into actual `Date` objects, using a decorator and moment, using [this guide](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/casting-date-string-from-http-json-response-using-decorator-in-angular-bbf8040e9d01) as inspiration.

I'm able to transform the actual dates, and logging the values of the response and the transformed model throughout the transformation works correctly.

My problem arises when trying to use/subscribe to the transformed response. When the decorator is present on the function that calls the backend, the value of the `next` parameter of `subscribe` on that call becomes `undefined`.

---

`_transformers/TransformDate.ts`

```js
import {map} from "rxjs/operators";
import * as moment from "moment";
import {PaginationResponse} from "@app/_models/paginationResponse";
import {BaseModel} from "@app/_models/basemodel";

export function TransformPaginationResponseDates(target:any, key:any, descriptor:any) {
  console.log('descriptor A', descriptor);
  const originalMethod = descriptor.value;
  descriptor.value = function () {
    return originalMethod.apply(this).pipe(
      map((obj: PaginationResponse<BaseModel>) => {
        obj.data?.forEach((model:BaseModel) => {
          Object.assign({}, model, stringToDate(model)) // correct dates in console
        });
      })
    )
  }
  console.log('descriptor B', descriptor); // same console output as descriptor A
  return descriptor;
}

const isDate = (s: string) => moment(s, moment.ISO_8601, true).isValid();

function stringToDate(obj:any) {
  return Object.keys(obj)
    .filter((key) => obj[key] && isDate(obj[key]))
    .map((key) => { obj[key] = moment(obj[key]).toDate() })
}
```

---

In the relevant service class

```js
@TransformPaginationResponseDates
getPaginatedList():Observable<PaginationResponse<Timer>> {
    return this.http.get<PaginationResponse<Timer>>(`${environment.apiUrl}/timer/list`);
}
```

---

In the relevant component

```js
this.timerService.getPaginatedList().pipe(first()).subscribe(paginationResponse => {
  console.log(paginationResponse); // undefined
});
```

The value of `paginationResponse` is as expected without the decorator, but is `undefined` when the decorator is used the function above.

However,

```js
const p = this.timerService.getPaginatedList().pipe(first()).subscribe();
console.log(p);
```

Shows the type to be `SafeSubscriber` in both cases.

---

`_models/paginationResponse.ts` (truncated)

```js
export class PaginationResponse<T> {
  currentPage?: number;
  data?: Array<T>
  ...
}
```

`_models/timer.ts`

```js
import {BaseModel} from "@app/_models/basemodel";

export class Timer extends BaseModel{
  name?: string;
  startedAt?:Date;
}
```

Where the server has responded with

```php
...
'startedAt' => $this->getStartedAt()->format(DateFormat::ISO_8601->value) // 'c'
...
```

---

Answer (score 1):

there are errors in the code. 1: nothing is returned from the map inside of decorator. there is plenty ways of fixing that, for example

```
map((obj: PaginationResponse<BaseModel>) => {
        return obj.data?.map((model:BaseModel) =>
          Object.assign({}, model, stringToDate(model)) // correct dates in 
        );
      })
```

2: stringToDate method returns an array instead of object. fixed version:

```
function stringToDate(obj:any) {
  Object.keys(obj)
    .filter((key) => obj[key] && isDate(obj[key]))
    .map((key) => { obj[key] = moment(obj[key]).toDate() })
  return obj;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This does at least return a defined result. It does however not return the entire PaginationResponse and only keeps one of the entries in .data. The investigation continues. I guess I'm still confused about pipes, maps and filters.